# Laravel Model Policy "Create" not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I've seached a lot and haven't found a solution for this issue.

When calling my resource controller create method, I'm always getting 403.

Other policies that work: view, update, delete

On the model policy:

```
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        $manager = app('impersonate');
        return ($user->hasRole('Psycologist') || $user->hasRole('Intern')) && !$manager->isImpersonating();
    }
```

On the controller:

```
    public function create()
    {
        $this->authorize('create', User::class);

        return view('personalarea::layouts.areas.employment.jobboard.employee.experience.create');
    }
```

On the AuthServiceProvider:

```
\\'App\Models\Employment\CandidateExperience' => 'App\Policies\JobCandidateExperiencePolicy',
CandidateExperience::class => CandidateExperiencePolicy::class,
```

Tried both versions and no difference.

Also made sure registerPolicies as set on boot.

```
$this->registerPolicies();
```

I've tried to call die("test") on the policy method and it makes no difference, it seems not be even called.

Any ideas?

Comment: missing a `)` in the return of your model policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is in this line:

```
 $this->authorize('create', User::class);
```

you should not pass the User::class, the user parameter will be injected by laravel not by you, you should pass the model type you want to create:

```
$this->authorize('create', CandidateExperience::class);
```

more details in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#via-the-user-model